# Transition's hook creates issue once destroyed and called back

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a parent and child component, in child component I have a `<transition>` defined like this:

```
<template lang="pug">
  div
    transition(name="fade-transition" mode="out-in" v-on:after-enter="fnAfterEnter")
      h1(v-if"someCondition") lorem ipsum
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      fnAfterEnter () {
        do something here...
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The problem is, in parent component I have some functions that will mount and destroy the child component with simple `v-if` condition. Things will work just fine for the first time child component is mounted but once destroyed and mounted back again `<transition>`'s all the hooks (not just `v-on:after-enter`) doesn't trigger methods `fnAfterEnter`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the expected behavior and what behavior you're actually seeing? The description you provided is difficult to understand as is.

Comment: @B.Fleming I fix the issue myself, posted the solution, pls have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was: the child component's transition was not completed and I was running some function in parent component to make child component's transition item condition `true` without using `$nextTick` but now I did like below code and the issue got fixed.

```
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      someFnInParent () {
        this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.$refs.childComp.someCondition = true
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

So, `this.$nextTick(() => {})` helped me :)